# Should I split my Django and DRF project into separate projects?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, entity-relationship, django-authentication, project-planning

I am currently at the planning stage of an app that will consist of standard

1. Django part for supervisors that can perform all CRUD operations on employee users mostly add, delete and view statistics - viewed in browser (no frontend framework just using Djangos server side rendering), two step email authentication on each login, session based auth
2. DRF part for employees - API connected to mobile app, authentication based on device ID. (no username, or password)
3. DRF part for clients to contact the supervisors if employees do something wrong - Token or JWT based authentication using passcode delivered by mail.

I am not used to splitting Django projects into multiple sub-projects (or using same database for different projects) but it feels like every part of the project should be a standalone app due to different authentication type and the fact of simultaniousily using DRF with standard Django

Can anyone who had similar problem or has some experience, advise what should I do considering different authentications and overall different user types in this project? What would be pros and cons of going into solo or multiple projects? 
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking for opinions, so don't be surprised if the question gets closed, but I'll answer with facts:

A split over different projects using the same database has the following issue: shared migrations. They all use built-in users, so require some standard apps to be enabled that have migrations and they won't run on the 2nd and 3rd project.

You're going to need a custom user model to support the device id authentication method: You need information that is not on the standard user model to be available at authentication time - the number 1 reason to create a custom user model. Ties into migrations and also a synchronization hell code-wise.

Django's Authentication Backends system allows for different authentication methods to exist at the same time, so there is no need to split anything. If you're worried about security, you can always use different hostnames and the Sites framework to add an extra layer of protection, but they would still use the same code.

DRF started as an addition to Django's view-based approach, not a replacement to make part of a project's code available as an API. While current usage is more "DRF or templates" this is a result of people increasingly becoming binary ("this" or "that") and wanting to be in the cool club, but has nothing to do with technical reasons. They can and always will be able to co-exist as they solve different problems. In fact, DRF's generic views make use of Django's CBV's and the built-in browsable API makes use of templates. Also, the admin is template/view based and it's convenient to develop the app or manage data with the built-in admin.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer this is kinda what I hoped for since I'm not used to using shared db. Do you have any reliable learning source for professional customization  of authentication backends ? I only used single AB to allow mail or username login so my knowledge is quire narrow. (I mean apart from Django docs which I read along with most of the source code on github)

Comment: I would suggest to look into django-allauth, it has a pretty complex authentication mechanism that uses a single authentication backend that coexists with Django's. Same goes for social-auth-app-django, which is used in [this excellent tutorial](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/#log-in-with-github).

Comment: How can we use both server-side rendered templates and the standard session authentication system, along with API endpoints and JWT authentication at the same time? How is that working with the standard permission system? I know DRF looks for the first successfull authentication method among several, but is it the same with serving a HTML template or a JSONResponse at the same URL?

Comment: @Hills DRF doesn't have a separate authentication mechanism, it just uses Django's, so it is the same system. This is why there are packages like [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/master/setup.py#L35) that can wrap django-allauth. The easiest example that they can co-exist, is to setup [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser) for a frontend, login (which will use JWT and your SPA) and then login to your admin (which will use session auth and server-side rendered pages).